# Running python script with chaquopy in android studio

Tags: python, android-studio, kotlin, chaquopy

so I'm new to android studio and right now I am writing my first app, and recently ran into a problem that I haven't been able to solve.

I've been trying to use chaquopy to call a function I wrote in python, but every time I try running the activity which calls the python code I get this error:
com.chaquo.python.PyException: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script'.
My python file's name is script.py

Here is the code I wrote for the part which calls the python code:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_page)

    if (!Python.isStarted())
        Python.start(AndroidPlatform(this))
    val py: Python = Python.getInstance()
    val pyobj: PyObject = py.getModule("script")

    date_choose()
    val search_btn: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.search)
    search_btn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        fun OnClick(view : View)
        {
            val obj : PyObject = pyobj.callAttr("SportsDemo",game_day,game_month,game_year)
            val diff_games: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.diff_games)
            diff_games.text = obj.toString()
        }


    })
```

If anyone has an idea of what I can do to fix this I would be glad if they helped me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the location of your Python file. From the [Chaquopy documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#source-code):

> By default, Chaquopy will look for Python source code in the python subdirectory of each [source set](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html#sourcesets). For example, the Python code for the main source set should go in `src/main/python`.